# How to update a git hub repository on command line

Tags: python, github, repository, git-pull

I would like to update a GitHub repository which can be found  https://github.com/south-coast-science 
I am doing this so that I can use a new command, however I'm not sure how to do this. I have tried using the pip install update method which did not work.

"sudo pip3 install SCS/ -U"

I think I may need to do a git pull but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Have you cloned the repo you want to update? and do you have romote origin setup?

Comment: @TumoMasire The repo has been cloned a few months ago but I am not sure about the remote origin set up

Comment: I think this is off topic for Stack Overflow. There are plenty of resources on the subject. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

The process of downloading and updating a repo usually goes as follows:

```
git clone [remote repository URL]
# Clones the repo
git init
# initializes the local repo
git remote add origin [remote repository URL]
# Sets the new remote
git remote -v
# Shows the new remote URL
```

From here you can modify or add the files you want using

```
git add [file name(s)]
# Adds files to commit
git commit -m "commit message"
# Creates the commit, with a message
git push origin master
# Pushes the changes in your local repository up to the remote repository you specified as the origin
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but if I have already installed the repo previously do I need to do it again ? I just want to update it so it adds a few of the new commands

Comment: if you have the repo installed, then just open a command line prompt in the folder and run: git remote -v . It should show you if you have a remote origin connected.

Comment: If you have a remote origin, then you can edit the files you want, and run: git commit -am "message" . To add all modified files (the -a flag). If you create new files, you will need to use: git add file.name to add it, before you run: git commit.

Answer (score 0):

here is how to add an existing project to github

https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line